# Hide the disabled icon on disable form field

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm working on a Vue project. In a form, I have a field that is sometimes disabled, meaning not clickable. When I hover over the field I see the typical "disabled icon"

[image]

I would like to hide the icon and instead don't display any cursor nor icon.
I've made many attempts with CSS, among other

```css
cursor: none
```

but it didn't work. Any advice?

Comment: What is the actual css selector you have tried? I'd think that `input[disabled]:hover { cursor: default; }` works unless you are using a framework that defines something else.

Comment: which ui framework are you using?

Comment: I use Vue in combinaison with Quasar.  I've tried `input[disabled]:hover { cursor: default; }`, but it didn't work, may be because of Quasar?